# Using BufferedWriter in an infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Is it possible for me to use a BufferedWriter (or any writer class for that matter) to output a new line to a text file during each iteration of an infinite loop until the program is stopped? To my understanding, the BufferedWriter.close() command must be called for the text to be saved onto the file, but if the writer is closed within the loop, the program will throw an exception - obviously, if the writer is set to close outside the loop, the statement is unreachable. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's the relevant code:

```
             int count = 0;
             BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myTextFile.txt"));
             while (true) 
             {

                if(count == 0){
                    out.write(myString);
                    out.newLine();
                    System.out.println(myString);
                } else {
                    out.append(myString);
                    out.newLine();
                    System.out.println(myString);

                }
                System.out.println("count = " + count);
                count++;
                out.flush();
                out.close();                   
             }
```

Comment: And you can't just put the close functions *outside* of the while loop?

Comment: Why not have a value determine when to stop looping, set that value when you want the program to exit, and then close your resource after the loop.  Are you forced  to have an infinite loop or don't control when the program closes?

Comment: @Austin If the writer is closed outside an infinite loop, that statement will not be reached.

Comment: @aherbets oh whoops...totally blanked on that. :(

Comment: @Andrew_CS - I'm using an infinite loop because the program is receiving text over a multicast every 90 seconds - text which is parsed and then updated to the text file - and that has to continue until the user stops the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make sure all data is written to file, **flush** will do it. Close is mostly to release the resource, especially if you are calling flush explicitly

flush - Flushes the stream.

close - Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush%28%29) method and extract your [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29) in the `finalize()` method.

Using [Flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush%28%29) will allow you to see the result in your text file while your app write in it.

When you stop your application, the GC will call finalize method and close the stream.

Comment: When you use the flush method, the buffer will be flushed to the disk and you will be able to see the content in your file.